# object contact list javascript so many mistakes

Tags: javascript, function, object

this is my first time making a contact list.Object is still a riddle to me. i'm so deep in the rabbit hole. i don't know how to get back on track

Instructions -

a. Create a factory Function called makeContact(id, nameFirst, nameLast) 
that returns a contact object.

b. Create a factory Function called makeContactList that returns an Object 
that manages contacts. The contact-list object should have the following API:

1. addContact(contact): takes a contact object to be added to the 
   contact-list.
2. removeContact(contact): takes a contact object to be removed from 
   the contact-list.

3.length(): returns the number of contacts within the list.

4. find(fullName): takes a full-name String, like 'Max Gaudin', and 
   returns the contact object if found in the contacts-list, or, 
   undefined if the fullName does not match any contacts in the list.

   ```
       var contacts = require('./data/contact.json');

      // YOUR CODE GOES BELOW HERE //
      function makeContact(id, nameFirst, nameLast) {

      var contacts = []; 
            return    {
            id: id,
            FirsName: nameFirst,
            LastName: nameLast
            };

            } 
            function makeContactList(id, nameFirst, nameLast) {
            var contacts = [];
            return { 
                 id: id,
                 FirstName: nameFirst,
                  LastName: nameLast,


      You need something here to hold contacts. See length api for a
   ```

   hint:

   ```
   // we implemented the length api for you //
   length: function() {
       return contacts.length;
    },
     addContacts: function(contact){
      return contacts.push();
    },
      removeContacts: function(contact){
      contacts.splice(contact);
    }

        return contacts;
    },
      find: function(fullName) {

       return contacts(fullName);
     }
     };
      }
   ```

I cleaned it and i'm trying to start fresh, take it one step at a time and do more reading. After i get done studying and understanding functions, loops, objects, etc etc, but i get totally lost. i want to understand how to do this.

Comment: So many problems... you require the json data but then you reassign to it in the `makeContact` function, you have `return` statements inside `for` loops, wow.

Comment: in function makeContactList take out id, nameFirst, and NameLast? i'm all about trials and errors. thank you for your input!

Comment: Trial and error is not random. You are trying to make random changes until you get the desired outcome. That won't work. Even this trivial task is too complex for that. You are going to have to either manually or in your head be able to *follow* the control flow through the program and check or visualize what the values of the variables are. If you don't feel comfortable using the debugger, then `console.log` is your friend.

Comment: i totally get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the solution. After doing some reading and watching videos.

```
  var contacts = require('./data/contact.json');

      function makeContact(id, nameFirst, nameLast) {
       return {
       id: id,
   nameFirst: nameFirst,
   nameLast: nameLast

 };
 }
     function makeContactList(id, nameFirst, nameLast) {
    var contacts = [];
    return { 
        id: id,
        nameFirst: nameFirst,
        nameLast: nameLast, 



    // we implemented the length api for you //
    length: function() {

        return contacts.length;

    },
    addContact: function(contact){

      return contacts.push(contact);
    },
    removeContact: function(contact){
        for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
           if(contacts[i] === contact) {
        return contacts.splice(i, 1);
           }
        }
    },
    find: function(fullName) {
        for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            if(fullName === contacts[i]["nameFirst"] + " " + contacts[i]["nameLast"]) { 
            return contacts[i];
            }
        }
    }   
    };    
   }
```